# Redirect to another page React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Why It doesn't redirect to another page??

```
findUtente(cf) {
    let params = {};
    console.log(cf)
    params = {
      "Person.FiscalCode": cf
    };
    global.utente.db
      .localdb()
      .find({
        selector: params
      })
      .then(response => {
        let utente = response.docs[0];
          console.log("You are here 1")
          utente.Person.FirstName = this.state.FirstName;
          utente.Person.LastName = this.state.LastName;
          //return global.utente.db.localdb().put(utente);
          global.utente.db.localdb().put(utente);
          console.log(global.utente.db.localdb().put(utente))
          console.log("You are here 2")
          Alert.alert("Modifica Effettuata")
          Actions.HomepageUtente();
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      })
```

The console log print only "You are here 1".

This is the button that call this function

```
<View style={style.footer}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
                onPress={() => this.findUtente(this.props.cf)}
              >
                <Text style={style.buttonTesto}>Modifica</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
```

How can I do? Thank you

Comment: remove `console.log(global.utente.db.localdb().put(utente))`

Comment: @khan yes, i use Couch/Pouch

Comment: @hongdevelop doesn't change :(

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved using:

```
.finally(function() { Actions.linktopage ) });
```